# Solve matrix equation $AXB+CX=D$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

How to solve matrix equation $AXB+CX=D$ for $X$? If it is not solvable, are there any numerical methods to do it?

Comment: Unless some invertibility/commutativity conditions are given, it doesn't look good. About numerical methods: you're not going to like the one I'm thinking of, that is to open up the left side and compare with the RHS...terrible.

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, this reduces to [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). If the eigenvalues of $CA^{-1}$ and $-B$ are disjoint, the matrix equation is invertible and it has unique solution. There are integral and series representations for the solution and there are numerical algorithms to compute $X$. Look at the ref in above wiki page as a start.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the vec operation to both sides of the equation to obtain a linear system
$$\eqalign{
 (B^T\otimes A + I\otimes C)\,{\rm vec}(X) &= {\rm vec}(D) \cr
}$$
whose solution is
$$\eqalign{
 {\rm vec}(X) &= (B^T\otimes A + I\otimes C)^{-1} \,{\rm vec}(D) \cr
}$$
Or, if the inverse does not exist, you may need to resort to the pseudoinverse.